# Registration of backend webgl failed for tensorflowjs

Tags: google-chrome, tensorflow, webgl

As suggested in tensorflowjs github, I post the question here. I am getting below error, in simplest example possible with tensorflow.

**Error:**
[image]

**Code:**  A simple html snippet with just tfjs loading.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@0.15.3/dist/tf.min.js"></script>
    <title>Testing Tfjs</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Testing Tfjs</h2>    
</body>
</html>
```

Browser: Chrome Version 72.0.3626.119
OS: Win 10, GPU: GT 740M, version 397.44.
Chrome gpu show says : (because I disabled hw acceleration to avoid chrome blacking out at times)

```
WebGL: Software only, hardware acceleration unavailable, 
WebGL2: Software only, hardware acceleration unavailable
```

I have tried setting backend explicitly as cpu but it did not help. I have seen other posts in github talking about this error, but in vain.

Comment: Note: That message is just a warning AFAICT. Tensorflow logs it as a warning and falls back to CPU mode so just ignore the message. Otherwise does webgl work for you in general? The code you posted does not generate an error for me. Maybe your device doesn't actually support WebGL? What OS? What GPU? What Driver version? What does about:gpu show in Chrome?

Comment: Hi, I did confirm webgl works in my browser which I checked [here](https://get.webgl.org/). Nevertheless here are more details: OS: Win 10, GPU: GT 740M, version 397.44. gpu show says : ```WebGL: Software only, hardware acceleration unavailable, WebGL2: Software only, hardware acceleration unavailable```. If webgl is not working, why get.webgl.org says it is working? [This](http://webglreport.com/) website also confirms webgl working in my browser.

Answer (score 5):

sorry, my english is not good.

Same as my case.
in my case...
"WebGL is not supported on this device" and
"tf.setBackend('webgl')" return false.

Tensorflow require hardware acceleration.

open chrome://gpu, then check your

- Graphics Feature Status
- Problems Detected
- Graphics Feature Status for Hardware GPU
- Problems Detected for Hardware GPU

Problems Detected.

> Gpu compositing has been disabled, either via blocklist, about:flags or the command line. The browser will fall back to software compositing and hardware acceleration will be unavailable.
> Disabled Features: gpu_compositing

then goto chrome://flags/
search "Override software rendering list" > set enabled > restart browser

thx.

Answer (score 0):

So since you posted your about:gpu result showing that you're only getting software rendering only for WebGL that suggests tensorflow.js is passing in the `failIfMajorPerformanceCaveat` context creation flag to WebGL which will almost certainly fail under software rendering

We can check by overriding `getContext` and print out the creation flags

```html
<script>
HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.getContext = function(type, parameters) {
 console.log(JSON.stringify(parameters, null, 2));
 return null;
};
</script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@0.15.3/dist/tf.min.js"></script>
```

So running that I see these results

```
{
  "alpha": false,
  "antialias": false,
  "premultipliedAlpha": false,
  "preserveDrawingBuffer": false,
  "depth": false,
  "stencil": false,
  "failIfMajorPerformanceCaveat": true    <====-------
}
```

So that's why it prints that warning.

That said it's just a **warning**. tensorflow.js still runs. Notice (a) it says 2 warnings, not 2 errors. (b) they are displayed in yellow, not red.

[image: warnings not errors]

using `console.warn` vs `console.error` you can see the difference

[image: warning vs error]

tensorflow.js runs just fine AFAICT. Here's an example. I've hacked `getContext` so it always fails so tensorflow.js can't get a WebGL context. It prints the 2 warnings but it also runs just fine. Scroll to the bottom of the messages and you'll see it ran the example tensorflow code's results.

```js
const d = tf.tensor2d([[1.0, 2.0], [3.0, 4.0]]);
const d_squared = d.square();
d_squared.print();
```

```html
<script>
HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.getContext = function() {
 return null;
};
</script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@0.15.3/dist/tf.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Explaining the difference between warnings and errors is not the purpose of the question and is not helping. If you have the warnings, the performances are so low because of the non-accelerated computation that it makes the model unusable.

Comment: It is the point of the question. The questioner thought tensorflow was not working. It was working. The questioner showed gpu accleration is disabled on their computer as well. They even said they forced it to CPU oinly and again thought it wasn't working but it was.